# How to add a validation on a float property in a api using JavaX / SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api

When spending a postman request to my API, I would like an error to be thrown when I enter a value that is outside the max value for a float, 3.4028235e+38f. (I am using Java & Spring Boot)

I have tried to use a float which was the requirement for the particular field but I haven't been able to work it out. I have tried using a decimal instead but have still not manage to get the error i expected displayed in postman.

```
// @Max(34028235 + 38)
// MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffeP+127f; // 3.4028235e+38f
//Long maxFloatValue = longValue(3.4028235e+38f);
//@Range(max= (longValue(3.4028235e+38f)))
//@Max(maxFloatValue)
@JsonProperty("RequestedAm")
private Float requestedAm;

//@Max (340282300000000000000000000000000000000);
//@JsonProperty("RequestedAm")
//private BigDecimal requestedAm;`
```

I would like an error to be displayed in postman like it does for the Strings when using Min and Max but not sure how this works for a float or as near as?

Comment: Please show your controller method and the full DTO that you're deserializing into. There are additional annotations required to get Spring to automatically apply the validation annotations.

Comment: I have spring working and it validate all other inputs including String, Integer Etc but its just Float I am not sure the correct validation to use

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the javax.validation `@Max` annotation, the JavaDoc states that float an double types are not supported (due to rounding errors). You could try using `BigDecimal` in your controller (DTO?), then converting as necessary after validation has been run.

Alternatively, you could write a custom validator that does the work, but keep in mind the warning about potential rounding errors - if it were simple the javax.validation annotations would already do it.